# how to place two tables horizontally within a pdf file?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pdf, itext

I have created two tables on pdf file. Now I wants to arrange them in horizontal position. That is table 1 should be at left of page, and table 2 should be at the exact right position of table 1. But when Iam doing, table 1 comes correctly, but table2 is not exact horizontal with table1.table 2 is just placed as left aligned. How can I place this table 2 as horizontally parallel with table1?

```
   var doc1 = new Document(PageSize.A4);
   PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, new FileStream(path + "/" + pdf_name + "", FileMode.Create));
            doc1.Open();

  var table1 = new PdfPTable(1); //table1
           table1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
           table1.SpacingBefore = 50;
           table1.DefaultCell.Border = 1;
           table1.WidthPercentage = 40;
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(student_name, boldTableFont));
             cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            table1.AddCell(cell);
            doc1.Add(table1);


           var table2= new PdfPTable(1); //table2

           table2.DefaultCell.Border = 1;
           table2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;

           table2.SpacingBefore = 50;
           table2.WidthPercentage = 40;

              PdfPCell cell21 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("success", body));
             cell21.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
             table2.AddCell(cell21);
           doc1.Add(table2);
           doc1.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new table with a single row and two columns.

```
Place first table in the first row first column and second table in the first row second column
```

**Give the alignment of the first column as left , and for the other right**

hope this helps..

Comment: this is just a sample, actually table 1 consist 1 column and 5rows. And table2 have 1column and 7rows. So is this idea will be helpful ?

Comment: @user2830487..i didnt see any problem..if number of columns are less, reduce the width of the master table which contains these two tables. give border as none to it. tables are best way to properly align your elements either in pdf docs or html ..